# repost form to a different action (not from my site) and add additional data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http

I would like to do this because I need to post to a foreign site, and would like to avoid setting a hidden input inside the form because the user might change the value inside of it (or somebody else might do it for him)

my html:

```
<form action="<%=Url.Action("prepare") %>" >
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

and my Action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Prepare()
{
   if(Request.IsAuthenticated)
   {
      //post to "http://example.com/do" 
      //and add to the request userId = User.Identity.Name
      return //the result of the repost
   }
   else 
   {
      return RedirectToAction("youneedtobeloggedin",);
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you have control over the remote site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep everything server side, you can take a look at [here](http://en.csharp-online.net/HTTP_Post). It's a simple way to perform POSTs programmatically. In this way you'll handle external POSTs all server side. Please beware that this will make your server perform the POST.

In your controller you can have this Action:

```
[HttpGet]
public string MyActionPostingToRemote() 
{
  string postResult = HttpPost (remoteUrl, remotePostQueryString);
  return postResult;
}
```

The HttpPost is the function you can find in my link.

Comment: He wants to return the response from the remote site to the browser.

Comment: well that's easy. If the triggering action returns string he can return the POST response, or he can parse it and build up a new model and then redirect to a view. However I'll edit in order to state this a bit clearly.

Comment: I suppose it returns a string. But this string represents HTML. And this HTML probably has some javascript and CSS files associated to it. So that would be a problem to display them.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: good point. In that case is better to parse the response and return a View on his application. Sure it adds a bit of complexity, but if OP wants to avoid client side hijack I suspect is the safer method. However as usual, it depends on the particular case. What do you suggest for avoiding a server side POST ?

Answer (score 0):

Cross-site calls are not allowed by modern browsers. Because of security.